# Problem finding suitable power series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, power-series

I am facing the following problem.

Suppose that $a_0,...,a_n$ satisfy the triangular system of equations:

$\frac{1}{0!}=\frac{a_0}{1!}, \frac{1}{1!}=\frac{a_0}{2!}+\frac{a_1}{1!}, ..., \frac{1}{n!}= \frac{a_0}{(n+1)!}+\frac{a_1}{n!}+...+\frac{a_n}{1!}$

and consider the function $A(x):=\sum_{m=0}^{n}a_mx^m$. Find power series $B(x)$ and $C(x)$, centered on $x=0$, with $B(0)\neq 0$, such that all terms of the expression $A(x)B(x)-C(x)$ have degree greater than $n$.

The only thing I have achieved is to deduce the following expression:

$\frac{1}{k!}=\sum_{j=0}^{k}\frac{a_j}{(k+1-j)!}.$

I have no idea how to proceed ... can someone give me light?

Comment: Looks like the coefficients of $A(x)\frac{e^x-1}{x}$

Comment: Do you suggest to do $B(x)=\frac{e^x-1}{x}$ and $C(x)=-\frac{A(x)}{x}$ ?... If this is correct, I think that I'm confused with the concept "degree"

Comment: Let $A(z)=\sum_{n\geq0}a_n z^n$. The series with coefficients $\frac{1}{(n+1)!}$ is $\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{1}{(n+1)!}z^n=\frac{1}{z}\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{1}{n!}z^n=\frac{e^z-1}{z}$
The identity $\frac{1}{k!}=\sum^k_{j=0}a_j\frac{1}{(k+1-j)!}$ implies that the reaction the $A$ satisfies is
$$e^z=A(z)\frac{e^z-1}{z}$$

Comment: I understand everything you tell me, but I can't see how you got the last equality, I can't manipulate the series to reach that conclusion ...

Comment: This is Cacuhy's formula for product of series: $\Big(\sum^\infty_{n=0}a_nz^n\Big)\Big(\sum^\infty_{n=0}b_nz^n\Big)=\sum^\infty_{n=0}c_nz^n$, where $c_n=\sum^n_{j=0}a_jb_{n-j}$. Try to identify from your problem what is $b_n$ and what is $c_n$.

Comment: sure! ... I forgot it completely!
thank you very much for your help!